# Making a joint plot of calculated data using Seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, physics

I want to create a 2D joint plot with the following data and from what I've read Seaborn is the best solution for this

I have completed a desired 1_D line plot, and have attempted to create the joint plot in Seaborn by putting the equations for each plot in the respective axes.

I am expecting the plot on the x axis to look similar to the plot I created using matplotlib and therefore the jointplot should have some vertical lines through the circular region.
However the plot output from seaborn on the x axis appears to have smoothed out many of the data points desired giving a smooth curve.

From reading about Seaborn it may not fit my needs for this kind of data, I have attempted using a matrix also but it did not seem to work with Seaborn.

This is the code I used

```
#imported as required

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

#Set limits for y values (x - axis)
ymin=-.6 
ymax= .6

#Set up an array of angle values between defined y values in mm
angle = np.linspace(np.deg2rad(ymin), np.deg2rad(ymax), 1000)

# Define known values
L = 480                        
a = 0.09
d = 0.4
lam = 670e-6

# Calculate values for position y, alpha and beta
y = np.tan(angle)*L
alpha = (np.pi*a/lam)*np.sin(angle)
beta = (np.pi*d/lam)*np.sin(angle)


I = ((np.sin(alpha)/alpha)**2)*((np.cos(beta))**2)

# Plot the graph of intensity versus displacement
plt.plot(y, I)

import seaborn as sns

p = ((np.sin(alpha)/alpha)**2)*((np.cos(beta))**2)    # Interference term and decaying term 
q = (np.sin(alpha)/alpha)**2                          # Decaying term            

sns.jointplot(x=p, y=q, kind='kde',marginal_kws=dict(bw=0.6),bw=0.8)
plt.show()
```

You might recognize this as famous the Double Slits Experiment

[These are the outputs. Note the smooth plot on Seaborn x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R34LL.png)

edit: I have used JointGrid as follows to plot on the axes in an attempt to solve the problem

```
g = sns.JointGrid(x=p, y=q)
g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot)
g.plot_marginals(sns.kdeplot)
```

I am not familiar with Seaborn syntax, so this simple snippet is all I could get to give an output, which had the same problem as my initial attempt.

Comment: Plot directly on the axes. `jointplot` returns a JointGrid. You can access the axes as attributes of that object

Comment: (see the sixth example in the JointGrid docs http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid)

Comment: Hi Paul, I have looked through the examples you linked, and used the JointGrid as detailed in my edited question. I was unable to work out the syntax and complete an example similar to the sixth you mentioned, but I managed to complete a simple approach. However I am not sure if this would fix my problem, as the kde plot seems to smooth out the data I need regardless.